# Change text size greyed out in Windows 8.1 - how do I make the UI larger

Tags: windows-8, modern-ui, dpi

I have just got a brand new 8" 1280x720 tablet but I found that the text size is too small. I entered PC Settings -> PC and devices -> Display but the "change the size of application, text and other items on the screen" is greyed out (I want to make it "larger").

How can I make the modern UI to become larger, as I do on my PC? For the desktop, I have already modified the registry to set the correct DPI (189)